# Kendo pager will not reset back to the first page

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a made a kendo datasource which makes a call out to my api, I have it limited to make pages of 10's. My problem is that the pager will not set back to the first page.  For example, when I make a call and to my api and receive 50 results, I will have 5 pages of 10 items each.  I select to go to the fifth page which, I then make another call and only receive 10 items which makes one page. However then the cal completes I am still on the 5th page; it will not reset to the first page.

```
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    page:1, << From what I read this is suppose to do the job
    pageSize: 10,
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: "POST",
            url: location + "/api/ContentSearch/SearchRequest",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            }
        },
        parameterMap: function (option, operation) {
            return JSON.stringify(query);
        }
    },
    change: function (e) {
        var data = this.data();
        $("#searchButton").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#loadingGif").hide();
        //kendoPager.page(1); << does not work
        switch (data.length) {
            case 0:
                FeedBackMessage("No result found");
                break;
            case 500:
                FeedBackMessage("Please check or refine the search");
                break;
            default:
                $('#pager').show();
                $('#descriptionColumn').show();
                $("#listView").show();
                $("#keyWordText").val("").data("kendoDropDownList").text("");
                $("#searchText").val("");

        }
        return data;
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $("#loadingGif").hide();
        ErrorHandler(e.sender.transport.options.read.url, e.xhr.status, e.xhr.statusText, "Kendo datasource was not binded to the WebApi response", "", true);           
    }
});

 function SubmitSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    query = {
        SearchText: $("#searchText").val(),
        KeywordText: generalContentKeywords.text(),
        GlobalSearch: true
    };
    if (query.SearchText === "" && query.KeywordText === "Select Category") {
        FeedBackMessage("Please enter a value");
    }
    else {
        if (query.KeywordText === "Select Category") {
            query.KeywordText = "";
        }
        $.when(TokenForWebApi()).then(function (adalToken) {

            token = adalToken;
            $('#pager').hide();
            $('#descriptionColumn').hide();
            $("#listView").hide();
            $("#searchButton").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#loadingGif").show();
            dataSource.read();
        });


    }
};

var kendoPager = $("#pager").kendoPager({
    dataSource: dataSource,
}).data("kendoPager");
```

Answer (score 0):

I went around this issue, by changing my submit function to see if the datasource has any data, and if it find that it does it reset set the page back to one.  I am guessing that my previous code, I was trying to set a page value before the datasource had any values to page.

```
   function SubmitSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    query = {
        SearchText: $("#searchText").val(),
        KeywordText: generalContentKeywords.text(),
        GlobalSearch: true
    };
    if (query.SearchText === "" && query.KeywordText === "Select Category") {
        FeedBackMessage("Please enter a value");
    }
    else {
        if (query.KeywordText === "Select Category") {
            query.KeywordText = "";
        }
        $.when(TokenForWebApi()).then(function (adalToken) {
            if (dataSource._pristineData.length) {
                kendoPager.page(1);
            }
            token = adalToken;
            $('#pager').hide();
            $('#descriptionColumn').hide();
            $("#listView").hide();
            $("#searchButton").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#loadingGif").show();
            dataSource.read();
        });
    }
};
```